# How to shorten javascript code that has an if statement in array spread

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to shorten this if statement in a reduce function. 
I tried using

```
acc = [...acc, v || ''];
```

but that just adds a empty string.

```
Object.entries(props).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    if (v) {
      acc = [...acc, v];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

I also want to not use the k in the [k, v] because linter is freaking out. How to not use the k variable but still get to the value variable ?

Comment: Have you got an example of the initial input, and the output you want - for clarification?

Comment: So you only want to add v to the array if v is truthy? Otherwise, add nothing, correct?

Comment: `acc = [...acc, v || ''];` works fine for me. What exactly is v?

Comment: v is sometimes null. which means the output array is adding null to it. ['item1', null]

Comment: `acc = v ? [...acc, v] : acc;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
acc = [...acc, ...(v? [v] : [])]
```

You could use a combination of the spread syntax like this.

The trick is, that `...` on an empty array will do nothing:

```
 [...[]] --> []

 [1, 2, 3, ...[]] --> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: [`...` is not an operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: @FelixKling correct, thank's for sharing. MDN lists it as 'spread syntax'.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary expression. You can use [array destructuring to skip the key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) (`k`) - `[, v]`:

```
Object.entries(props).reduce((acc, [, v]) => v ? [...acc, v] : acc, []);
```

However, a more functional solution (and since you don't need the key) would be to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) to get the same result:

```
Object.values(props).filter(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an empty array as default value and use `concat`, which resolves the empty array as neutral value.

For getting an item at a known index, you could destructure the array by taking the index.

```
result = Object
    .entries(props)
    .reduce((acc, { 1: v }) => acc.concat(v || []), []);
```

A shorter version should be to take only values.

```
result = Object
    .values(props)
    .reduce((acc, v) => acc.concat(v || []), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use `.concat()`, like so:

The reason this works is because concat (unlike push) will push the *contents* of an array to another array, rather than the array reference itself. By concatinating an empty array, it's essentially a no-op if `v` is falsey. This is the desired functionality, yeah?

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
var v = null;
var x = 4;
arr = arr.concat(v || []);
console.log(arr);
arr = arr.concat(x || []);
console.log(arr);
```

In your specific case:

```
Object.entries(props).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => acc.concat(v || []), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing unnecessary operations here: you basically create a new array every loop of reduce, and you're spreading the element of the previous one on top of it, just to add an element at the end!
It's basically what the method `push` does, so you can just use that:

```
Object.values(props).reduce((acc, v) => (v && acc.push(v), acc), []);
```